# If scalar field $f(x,y,z)$ is differentiable then the set of point satisfying $f(x,y,z)=c$ ($c$ is constant) is smooth surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, scalar-fields

Let $f(x,y,z), x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar field. Could you prove that if $f$ differentiable then the set of points $(x,y,z)$ sastifying $f(x,y,z)=c$ ($c$ is constant) is a smooth surface?

The definition of smoothness of surface bases on parametric form of surface, but this is not in parametric form, so I'm stuck.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant in some region? (It doesn't have to be constant everywhere; consider [smooth bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).) An equipotential set is not necessarily a surface.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem . This gives us $z=g(x,y)$ from $f(x,y,z)=c$, assuming that $\partial f/\partial z\neq0$. More generally, it's sufficient to have $\nabla f\neq0$.

Comment: @mr_e_man, I edited my question, not using the notion "equipotential surface" anymore. But I'm still confusing about this notion and want to ask more about it, see next comment for details.

Comment: @mr_e_man, I take the definition of "equipotential surface" from the book "classical mechanics point particles and relativity" of Walter Greiner (page 84), it said "*Equipotential surfaces*  are surfaces on which the function $\phi$  takes a constant value,  $\phi(x,y,z)=$  constant" (here,  $\phi$ play role as $f$). Does your first comment means  *equipotential surface*  may not the same as this definition? Could you give defintion of it in mathematical language (not using physics notions)?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$. The equipotential set $x^2+y^2=0$ is a vertical line, which is not a surface. But $\nabla f(x,y,z)=[2x,2y,0]=[0,0,0]$ on this line. If any function has $\nabla f\neq[0,0,0]$ everywhere on the equipotential set, then it is a surface; so your definition works in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ and a value $c\in{\mathbb R}$ the object
$$S:=f^{-1}\bigl(\{c\}\bigr)=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb R}^3\bigm| f(x,y,z)=c\bigr\}\quad$$
is a subset of the domain ${\mathbb R}^3$ of $f$, and is called a *level set* of $f$. Under reasonable assumptions such level sets are smooth surfaces, but we have to expect singularities.

If $p:=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point of $S$, and if $\nabla f(p)\ne{\bf 0}$ then we have, e.g., ${\partial f\over\partial z}(p)\ne0$. In this case there is a rectangular box $R$ with center $p$ and a $C^1$-function $(x,y)\mapsto z:=\psi(x,y)$ such that $S\cap R$, i.e., the part of $S$  lying in $R$, coincides with the graph of $\psi$. This means that we have a parametric representation of $S\cap R$ as follows:
$$\quad R'\to{\mathbb R}^3,\qquad (x,y)\mapsto\bigl(x,y,\psi(x,y)\bigr)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $R'$ denotes the "floor" of the box $R$. $(1)$ shows that in the neighborhood of $p$ the level set $S$ is indeed a smooth surface.

But in the critical points of $f$ there will be trouble. If, e.g., $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ then the level set belonging to $c=0$ is a single point. For  $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2$ and $c=0$ we obtain  the union of two intersecting planes, with all points on the $z$-axis "singular".